# How to use shell pipes to conditionally display output based on the exit code?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdout

I have a `foobar` command that is always verbose and I want to display its output (stdout and stderr) to the console only when foobar exit code is an error code.

I want to achieve this **without saving the output to a temp file**. I already know that workaround but I don't want to generate new files.

It is implied that the downside of such solution would be that the entire output will be seen only when foobar ends, as only then we will know if it was successful or not.

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Comment: Also is there a reason you can't use a file?

Comment: That's not a workaround; it's what you have to do. The shell isn't buffering the output for you in any other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try just saving the output in a variable. A simple one liner would be:

`r=$(foobar 2>&1) || echo "$r"`

Comment: I spotted one important downside from this, when using this approach I loose ANSI coloring which I do not want to.

Comment: @sorin ANSI codes should work fine, and they do in my tests. `r=$(printf "\\033[33mHello\\033[39m\n"; exit 1) || echo "$r"` prints "Hello" in yellow on my terminal. The echo doesn't interpret escape sequences but your foobar command should be doing that if you are getting colors when running it directly.

Comment: Indeed, I only had to enforce their use but this is needed with any wrapper. I implemented your solution in the end, no external tools.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `chronic` utility:

> chronic runs a command, and arranges for its standard out and standard error to only be displayed if the command fails (exits nonzero or crashes).  If the command succeeds, any extraneous output will be hidden.

Availability:

- `apt-get install moreutils` on Debian/Ubuntu
- `brew install moreutils` on MacOS (OSX)
- `yum install moreutils` on RHEL(epel)/Fedora/CentOS